# MachForm, RackForms(FromBoss), Form Tools

Tags: forms

I am looking for a form builder solution that will allow rapid form development even by beginners, without needing much knowledge of programming. I prefer a solution that we can install on our servers.

I have 3 products shortlisted for further review: MachForm, RackForms(formerly FormBoss) and Form Tools

If anyone has used any of these products, I would appreciate your input on your experience with using these products and your recommendations.

Does anyone know of other products that I must be sure to include in my review?

We will eventually move over hundreds of forms to the chosen solution and I would like to make sure as much as I can that it will still be a viable solution in the coming years.

Comment: What are your requirements? Forms are to be filled online? What kind of output do you need? Do you want open source? What is your budget?

Comment: Do not make us do unnecessary work: [edit your question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/5658/edit) and include links to the three products you mention.

Comment: And you need to put is much more requirements: what form features, what output etc.? Why can't you choose between one of the three, there must be criteria that you want to base your decision on, and you don't know the answers yet. Tell us.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution that has no learning curve and can be installed on your server, then MachForms is a good choice.
RackForms has a LOT more functionality, but the learning curve is very, very steep.  The additional functionality also isn't likely to be necessary in most situations.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! I'd advise you to look here for tips how to improve your answer: [What is required for an answer to be high quality? - Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/2437). For example, you could add screenshots, include your own experiences with MachForms, etc...